# what is the proper way to send and receive json requests in django

Tags: json, django

There are lots of information regarding this topic, but it is still unclear to me what is the correct approach to send and receive json data in django. Whether to use the raw format or not.

Approach1: **NOT** using the raw format:

```
#client
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                x: $("#x").val(),
            },
            success: response,
            dataType: 'json',
            minLength: 0,
        });

# server - views.py:
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
@staff_member_required
def api(request):
    params = request.POST
```

Approach2: using the raw format:

```
# client
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "api",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    x: $("#x").val(),
                }),
                success: response,
                dataType: 'json',
                minLength: 0,
            });

# server - views.py:
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
@staff_member_required
def api(request):
    params = json.loads(request.data)
```

I think that when using the raw format, you can pass in lists but without the raw format it does not understand lists in your data.
On the other hand, approach2 requires JSON.stringify and json.dumps.
Also, I do not know why approach2 throws and exception that You cannot access body...
What I want to know is:

- Does it matter which approach I take?
- If so which approach is proper and why?
- If raw json if preferable, then why does it complain with the ajax
  request below (see error below)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is solved on [django ajax docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax):

> set a custom X-CSRFToken header to the value of the CSRF token. **This is often easier**, because many JavaScript frameworks provide hooks that allow headers to be set on every request.

Notice than popular solutions like [django-rest-framework](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/daccc2b8f3a1ebe104480748bfac8e92f17d4234/rest_framework/static/rest_framework/js/csrf.js#L43) is using header approach:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
      // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
      // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
      // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
  }
});
```

django docs suggestion approach:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually my main question was whether to send json data in raw form hence retrieving it with request.body. Also, regarding your answer, I do not understand how to use $.ajaxSetup with $.ajax. Is this even needed since I noticed ajax doc says that by default crossDomain is set to false?