# How i can solve the CSRF Fobidden(403) django rest framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, csrf, django-csrf

i'm working my project with django restframework, all is right except when i try to update a table, always appears the CSRF.

How i  can set CSRF cookie?
Thanks

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed3Al.png)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340163/what-is-the-proper-way-to-send-and-receive-json-requests-in-django/37340742#37340742

Comment: thanks danihp, this is useful, but my problem right now is with the api and admin, i can add data, but when i try to update o delete send me the screenshot error, is the same and admin.

Comment: You do not set it, django issues a request with `Set-Cookie` and the browser shall respond back with `Cookie`.  I bet your browser is misconfigured (i.e. do not accept cookies or only accept them from known parties).  Check the HTTP headers for `Set-Cookie` (in the GET that gives the admin form) and for `Cookie` (in the POST you send when you click `Save`)

Comment: Nestor can you also add your urls.py in the question? I once encountered same problem and turned out I made a mistake there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced this earlier today while switching development projects and added to an existing thread here: [Django CSRF Cookie Not Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set/37457075#37457075)

After checking the order of installed apps and middleware against the startproject template, clearing my browser cache resolved the issue.